# Is $\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}$ equal to $\arccos$ or $\arcsin$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is this correct?

$$\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}dx = \arccos(x) +c = -\arcsin(x) +c $$

Or is it just
$$\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}dx = -\arcsin(x) +c $$

because
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\arccos(x))=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}$$

Comment: Since $\arccos x={\pi\over2}-\arcsin x$, either will do. Don't forget your constant of integration ...

Comment: Both equations are wrong because you forgot the constant.

Comment: generally this answer is -arcsin(x) ?

Comment: with +c which of one is correct ?!

Comment: Either, he said either.

Comment: i dont understand if  arccosx != π/2−arcsinx whats the answer ?!

Comment: Maybe [this picture](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arcsine_Arccosine.svg) is helpful. Except for an additive constant, $\arccos$ and $-\arcsin$ are the same.

Answer (score 2):

We know that
$$
\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}dx = \arccos x +C_1.
$$
The constant $C_1$ can be manipulated as $1+C_2$, $1000-C_2$, or what ever we want. In this case, we will choose $C_1=-\dfrac\pi2+C_2$, then
$$
\arccos x +C_1=\arccos x -\dfrac\pi2+C_2.
$$
Using basic trigonometry identity, we know that $\arcsin x+\arccos x=\dfrac\pi2$. Try to draw the right triangle, you will easily prove it the identity. Hence
$$
\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-x^2+1}}dx
$$
can also be written as
$$
\arccos x +C_1\quad\text{or}\quad-\arcsin x +C_2.
$$
Both are interchangeably.